# Laravel ORM bulk insert

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I cannot insert multiple rows with Laravel ORM with one query using method Model::create($mainArray)

I have tried put multiple arrays in one main array which want to insert in database with one query, not with foreach and multiple queries.

My $mainArray looks like this:

```
    array:49 [▼
      0 => array:17 [▼
        "time" => "2019-06-09 07:00:00"
        "summary" => "Partly Cloudy"
        "icon" => "partly-cloudy-day"
        "precipIntensity" => 0
        "precipProbability" => 0
        "temperature" => 21.34
        "apparentTemperature" => 21.34
        "dewPoint" => 14.02
        "humidity" => 0.63
        "pressure" => 1024.32
        "windSpeed" => 2.72
        "windGust" => 7.77
        "windBearing" => 246
        "cloudCover" => 0.43
        "uvIndex" => 3
        "visibility" => 13.2
        "ozone" => 324.62
      ]
      1 => array:17 [▼
        "time" => "2019-06-09 08:00:00"
        "summary" => "Clear"
        "icon" => "clear-day"
        "precipIntensity" => 0
        "precipProbability" => 0
        "temperature" => 23.22
        "apparentTemperature" => 23.22
        "dewPoint" => 13.6
        "humidity" => 0.55
        "pressure" => 1024.09
        "windSpeed" => 0.87
        "windGust" => 7.69
        "windBearing" => 205
        "cloudCover" => 0.21
        "uvIndex" => 5
        "visibility" => 16.09
        "ozone" => 324
      ]
```

So when i try to insert one by one row in foreach with Model::create() method, that's working. But when i try to Model::create($mainArray) i got this error message:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: As far as I know, there's no "ORM" way to perform bulk inserts. Bulk inserts are primarily for performance, but instantiating a bunch of Eloquent objects has the potential to use a ton of memory. `Model::insert()` isn't an ORM method per se. Internally it calls `DB::insert()` unfortunately. Hence casts and mutators don't work.

Answer (score 1):

if no model involved, maybe you can use this,

```
DB::table('tablename')->insert($mainArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

In related model you can use [saveMany/createMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method for multiple insert. You can use insert() method that accepts an array of attributes. But you need to update created_at and updated_at manually.

```php
Model::insert($mainArray);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. This is method for related models, but my model is not related to any other model. When i try saveMany or createMany i get error: Call to undefined method Model::saveMany().

Comment: `Model::insert()` isn't an ORM method per se. Internally it calls `DB::insert()` unfortunately. Hence casts and mutators don't work. Your example is spot on. Time stamps need to be updated manually, as do other casts. As far as I know, there's no bulk insert for ORM objects.